databricks notebook pip install python wheel error
I try to install the python wheel in the dbfs in databricks.
I first run below to confirm that I have that python wheel.
display(dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/FileStore/python-wheels/"))


Then I did
%pip install /dbfs/FileStore/python-wheels/dp_utils-0.1.43-py3-none-any.whl

But I got error that 
I really don't know why. Anyone has any idea?

I found the reason. In databricks it doesn't say it clearly that shared cluster cannot access to the dbfs unless to set the IAM role permission. So if using shared cluster, %pip install /dbfs/FileStore/xxx doesn't work.
